# Excel - Stack Data based in Condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula, row

I want to stack a table based on this condition

[image]

I want to automatically stack all count of "Available" that is running minimum 4minutes and up on the table (screenshot above)

Here is the table reference

[image]

So far, there are only 1 "Available" running more than 4 minutes out of 3 "Available" who did not met the criteria, so only this 8mins running should show on the stacked table (on the 1st screenshot)

I hope my explanations are clear.

I can only do MAXIF based on the criteria "Available" on the table so only 1 result can be shown.

[image]

I want all "Available" that has running 4minutes and up to be listed and stacked on the table automatically and it should show blank if everyone is below 4 minutes.

Comment: Instead of stack you mean filter? What does Total 13 mean in your example? Also why post 3 text strings as picture? And why not post the table as data?

Comment: Filter is also possible but I want something like automatically being populated when my criteria is met. In the example, the Total 13 means there are 13 Agents who are currently in Available Status, but for my question, I only want to show Available agents who are running 4 minutes and higher. Is this possible using ROW Function?

Comment: I can use filter but I had to do it every time if my table refreshes. Besides that, I also have to do this for all other criteria like "On Call", "Break", "Lunch", I need all agents be stacked in a row that will meet certain criteria. I just need a simple idea from my initial question to get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
=TEXT(SORT(FILTER(B:B,(B:B>=TIMEVALUE("00:04:00"))*(A:A="Available"),""),1,1),"h:mm:ss")
```

It appears you tried Filter but you should not need to change anything as it is dynamic.

**EXPLANATION:**

You are filtering column B where the time value is greater than 4 mins and the corresponding value in column A is "Available". Then you are simply converting the excel format of `TIME` into a readable time value.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry I replied to a wrong comment from another post but this works perfectly fine.

Comment: Now, how do I sort the data result from highest to lowest duration from this formula you suggested?

Comment: and is it also possible to apply conditional formatting on this one?

Comment: In order to sort the results just wrap it in a `SORT`. Check update. As for Conditional Formatting there is no reason you could not have rules set up. To my knowledge it can't be a dynamic range but you could say a set range to be a color or bold etc pending it's value.